# Tensorflow: Can I combine several name_scopes into one for optimizer update?

Tags: tensorflow

I have two named scopes for separate subgraphs of a CNN (using tf.variable_scope).  Can I combine the two scopes into one so that my optimizer updates only the variables in the two scopes?

Answer (score 13):

According to the [tf.Optmizer documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer), the function `minimize` can take a var_list (these vars reference the learned variable weights inside the graph).  So using that you just need to get a list of variables (like [w1, b1] for a simple MLP) from the graph.

---

If you have named them with tf.variable_scope, you should be able to use `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLESscope="my_scope_name")`, as described in the [tf.get_collection documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#get_collection).  If you have two variable scopes to get, you should be able to get the combined list with the `+` operator, as the call returns a python list.

---

So, comining the two ideas, I believe you can do:

```
loss = ...
vars_to_minimize = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='var_scope_name_1') + 
                   tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='var_scope_name_2')
minimize_op = tf.Optimizer().minimize(loss, var_list=vars_to_minimize)
```

---

Note: see [GraphKeys documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#GraphKeys) for more details on availabe keys to use in the get_collection call.

Comment: Just accepted your answer..... but I don't think the tick got reflected because I have "less than 15 reputation"..